# PHP Explode between an integer and letter

Tags: php, regex, explode

```
array (    
    [0] => 3 / 4 Bananas
    [1] => 1 / 7 Apples
    [2] => 3 / 3 Kiwis
    )
```

Is it possible, to say, iterate through this list, and `explode` between the first letter and first integer found, so I could seperate the text from the set of numbers and end up with something like:

```
array (
   [0] => Bananas
   [1] => Apples
   [2] => Kiwis
   )
```

I have no idea how you would specify this as the delimiter. Is it even possible?

```
foreach ($fruit_array as $line) {
   $var = explode("??", $line);
}
```

Edit: updated example. exploding by a space wouldn't work. see above example.

Comment: what is the format of the list, is it a string or array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `preg_match` instead of `explode`:

```
$fruit_array = array("3 / 4 Bananas", "1 / 7 Apples", "3 / 3 Kiwis");
$result = array();
foreach ($fruit_array as $line) {
   preg_match("/\d[^A-Za-z]+([A-Za-z\s]+)/", $line, $match);
   array_push($result, $match[1]);
}
```

It will almost literally match your expression, that is, a digit `\d`, followed by one or more non-letters `[^A-Za-z]`, followed by one or more letters or whitespace (to account for multiple words) `[A-Za-z\s]+`. This final matched string, between parentheses, will be *captured* in the first match, i.e., `$match[1]`.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FZJdt)**.

Comment: What if the fruit name had two words, like `Green Apples`? Your example would match just `Green`

Comment: @Norse: Just add an extra `\s` to `[A-Za-z]` to match whitespaces. This way, it also matches multiple words. I've edited my answer and my demo.

Answer (score 3):

```
// An array to hold the result
$result = array();

// Loop the input array
foreach ($array as $str) {

  // Split the string to a maximum of 2 parts
  // See below for regex description
  $parts = preg_split('/\d\s*(?=[a-z])/i', $str, 2);

  // Push the last part of the split string onto the result array
  $result[] = array_pop($parts);

}

// Display the result
print_r($result);
```

The regex works like this:

```
/
  # Match any digit
  \d
  # Match 0 or more whitespace characters
  \s*
  # Assert that the next character is a letter without including it in the delimiter
  (?=[a-z])
/i
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/wEjguHUn)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to explode "between the first letter and the first integer found" you shouldn't use explode.

[The PHP `explode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) accepts a delimiter as its first argument:

> array **explode** ( string *$delimiter* , string *$string* [, int *$limit* ] )

That means it's not "smart" enough to understand a complicated rule like "between the first letter and the first integer found" - it only understands things like "split on '1'" or "split on 'A'". The delimiter has to be something concrete: a specific letter and a specific integer, for example. (ie "between the letter 'B' and the integer '4'")

For something more abstract/general, like what you described ("between the first letter and the first integer found") you will need a pattern. So the best bet is to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead, [like so](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vCPKzJ):

```
<?php

$myArr = [    
    "3 / 4 Bananas",
    "1 / 7 Apples",
    "3 / 3 Kiwis",
    "1 / 7 Green Apples",
];

for($i=0; $i<count($myArr); $i++) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo preg_replace("/^.*?\d[^\d[a-z]]*([a-z])/i", "$1", $myArr[$i]);
    echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag in preg_match:

```
$a = array('1/4 banana', '3/5 apple', '3/2 peach');

foreach ($a as $b) {
    preg_match('/[a-z]/', $b, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $pos = $matches[0][1]; // position of first match of [a-z] in each case
    $c[] = substr($b, $pos);  
}

print_r($c);


Array ( [0] => banana [1] => apple [2] => peach )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach ($fruit_array as $line) {
   $var = explode(" ", $line);
   $arr[$var[2]] = $var[3];
}

var_dump( $arr ) should output:

array (
   [0] => Bananas
   [1] => Apples
   [2] => Kiwis
   )
```